# Link Within Title Attribute

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, title, colorbox

I noticed that a lot of users were having the same issue, trying to
get a  link within one of the title attributes within the lightbox, ColorBox.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the title for one of the pictures in the grouped gallery that says something
like:

```
"My website: Click <a href:"http://thompson-mcclellan.com"
target="_blank">Here</a>"
```

for one of the pictures within my grouped
gallery.  But nothing shows up whenever I try to code it as you stated
in the discussion post above.

Here is my JQuery:

```
$("a[rel='portfolio'] #tmc").colorbox({title:'Click <a
href="http://thompson-mcclellan.com">Here</a>'});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<a id="tmc" href="images/portfolio/tmc.jpg" rel="portfolio"><img
src="images/portfolio/tmc_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Here is my example website:
http://abrielshipley.com/portfolio/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in your example page the id tmc is applied on the a tag and not on something inside it. So our selector is wrong. Just use `$('#tmc')`.

As far as the colorbox now, the title should be a function that returns the text to display, not a static string.

So

```
$("#tmc").colorbox({
     title: function() { 
               return 'Click <a href="http://thompson-mcclellan.com">Here</a>';
            } 
});
```

Comment: Minor correction: *(and it **is** wrong to have multiple elements with the same id)* but +1 for the rest =)

Comment: @David, indeed. Bad wording, but it also does not apply in the case as @Abriel correctly uses it only once. I just missed it when i scanned the html.

Comment: in which case you...um...still get to have the +1? =D